# Modify jquery datepicker CSS with beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I am using `beforeShowDay` and have assigned the class `specialDay` to particular days in my calendar; this works fine, however I am having trouble understanding how to style the class and how the css from theme roller is working in general. I have tried:

```
td .specialDate {
    background: #33CC66;
}
```

but this has no affect on the look of the calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, fortunately i found the answer. 
When you disable a day (set to "false") is valid to assign a class (".specialDate") to change the background color, but not if the date is enabled, because we have another styled anchor ("a") that overrides the class assigned to "td" anchor.

So, if your date is enabled to select and want to change the styles, you have to edit the inherited "a" anchor, like this:

```
.specialDate a { background: #33CC66 !important; }
```

It's very important that you add the "**!important**" (if you'll forgive the repetition) indication in order to override other settings.

Hope this can help!

Comment: It is really important the "!important" mark after background. Does anyone know why the need for this override? If I remove it, those default values still appear.

Answer (score 5):

Create your css style like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.specialDay, table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.specialDay a { 
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #fffac2 !important; 
    color: #006633;
    }
</style>
```

Then add your style to calendar using beforeShowDay option.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', highlightDays);


// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// highlightDays
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (SOME CONDITION TO DETERMIN SPECIAL DAY) {
            return [true, 'specialDay'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.specialDate span {background-color:#ff0000!important;}
```

if you want to disable transparency effect

```
.specialDate {filter:Alpha(Opacity=100)!important; opacity: 1!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ui calendar has a theme, you must disable the `background-image` for the specialDate attribute:

```
.specialDate a { 
    background-image: none !important;
    background: #33CC66 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever i'm using the JQuery UI stuff I use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to check out any styles being applied to particular elements, this will enable you to easily identify which CSS elements you need to play with.

Comment: I use firebug, Ithink that the current style is being applied from the default theme roller css:

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:#75C8FF url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_75C8FF_1x400.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
border:1px solid #3A9EE0;
color:#555555;
font-weight:normal;
outline-color:-moz-use-text-color;
outline-style:none;
outline-width:medium;

My question is then, how do I modify cells with the class .specialDay that already have the above applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit that will highlight either the current date or the date from the associated text box.

The style:

```
.dateHighlight a { background: #58585a !important; }
```

The script:

```
var pickerDate;
$("#pickerId").datepicker({
    // get the date to be highlighted; use today if no date
    beforeShow: function() {
        pickerDate = $("#pickerId").datepicker("getDate");
        if (pickerDate == null) pickerDate = new Date((new Date()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    },
    // add css class to the date
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if (date.getTime() == pickerDate.getTime()) {
            return [true, 'dateHighlight', '']
        }
        return [true]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using on click you can do all the css you need:

```
var checkin = $('.dpd1').datepicker()
.on('click', function (ev) {
        $('.datepicker').css("z-index", "999999999");
}).data('datepicker');
```